# BLE connectivity in the background in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-background-mode

I've got a CGM peripheral which advertises every five minutes, being discoverable only for several seconds. The aim is to be able to gather glucose data every five minutes, especially in the background.

The Flutter code works well in the foreground for both Android and iOS devices. After scanning and discovering the peripheral once, I'll attempt to reconnect to it with a timeout for next readings, and disconnect immediately after gathering data.

The issue is connecting while app is the background. The timeout option for `flutterBlueDevice.connect(timeout: Duration(seconds: 300)` doesn't seem to wait at all, reporting no device has been found. I understand that BLE connectivity is [limited](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) in iOS environment.

Is there any way I could get around this in Flutter? If not, what approach should I use to integrate native `corebluetooth` partially in my code for connection part? Also, what connection strategy works best for continuous readings in this case?

Comment: Can the peripheral indicate/notify when it has a new value.  If so, rather than polling a better approach is to simply remain connected and read the new data when it is available. You are not going to be able to initiate a connection from ios when the app is in the background because there is no trigger to make your app run every five minutes.

Comment: Reading briefly though [the spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=248025) it looks like the peripheral can also disconnect automatically after a period and then become reconnectable later.  If  that is what happens, then your app should simply call `Connect` as soon as it gets a disconnection from the peripheral. iOS will complete that connection in the background when the peripheral becomes reconnectable.

Comment: Yes, the peripheral is only available for a short period at regular five minute intervals, and will get disconnected afterwards. In this case, enabling `State Preservation and Restoration`, as described in the core-bluetooth documentation, is my only option for `Connect` to work the way you described, right? Seems `flutter-blue` doesn't support this out of the box, and I should modify the library.

Comment: State restoration is likely going to be necessary for the long-term operation of your app. As long as your app remains in memory, suspended, Bluetooth background mode will be sufficient, but eventually your app will be terminated because the system needs memory for some other app. State restoration will ensure that your app is relaunched in the background to complete the pending `connect`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, @Paulw11. So now the question is why the current flutter code isn't working as is.

Comment: Assuming you are using [this package](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue) it doesn't work because the package isn't written to work correctly with background mode core Bluetooth. When you call `Connect` it checks to see if the peripheral is in a list of discovered  peripherals and fails immediately if they aren't. This is not correct. It should use `retrievePeripheralWithIdentifier` to try and obtain a `CBPeripheral` instance and then call `connect` in that. The connect will complete when/if the peripheral becomes available

Comment: https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus is the active successor to that package by the way. Also, you can post your solution as an answer now if you'd like, @Paulw11

Comment: Ok.  The code in that library looks better.  It is always a good idea to link the packages you are using when asking questions.  It looks like you need to have a method channel observer for `onConnectionStateChanged` in your Dart code to handle the connected peripheral.  You can't simply `await` the connect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255229/discussion-between-sajad-and-paulw11).